# Application Crashing Only On Release Configuration

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build, release

Over the last little while I have been encountering some crashes that are absolutely baffling.  They will only appear on the Release Configuration of the application that I am building, and they also are difficult to reproduce.  A rigorous search of Google has also brought up not many (if any) answers.

Here is a relevant crash log, for the one crash that I'm trying to fix, and physically can't.  The crash occurs after I close a modal view controller and as the views inside of that modal view controller deallocate.  For reference, I am using Core Data and also have some objects created inside of the dismissed modal view controller that aren't inserted into any managed object context (perhaps that's it?).

[image: Crash Log 1]

Comment: Turn on Zombies and see what object is being overreleased

Comment: "*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d5c6550"  This is in UIKit, and all I see is machine code after the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updating this.

I had some try-catch logic which was causing ARC to over-release an NSString.  I found this by using the Zombies tool in Instruments.  When I updated this logic and removed the original try-catch logic, the problem was fixed.